# When I turn animation speed to zero, it works, but when turning it back to 1 it does not work in UnityScript

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So when I made a settings script that turned animations on and off with a checkbox, and when I turned the animations *off* it worked, but when I clicked the checkbox again, the animations wouldn't turn off again.
Here is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AnimationSettings : MonoBehaviour {

public Toggle TheCheckbox; 

public Animator[] TheAnimators;

[SerializeField] int thelength;

public static int animationsetting;

void Awake(){

    thelength = TheAnimators.Length;
    DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject.transform);
}

public void SaveSettings(){

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Animations", animationsetting);
    PlayerPrefs.Save ();
}



public void SetAnimationSettings(){

    bool onoroff = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Animations") == 1;

    if (onoroff)
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Animations", 1);
    if (!onoroff) 
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Animations", 0);

    PlayerPrefs.Save ();

    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Animations") == 0) {




        for(int i=0; i<=thelength-1; i++){

            Animator animforthisround = TheAnimators[i];
            animforthisround.speed = 0;

        }

    } else if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Animations") == 1){



        for(int i=0; i<=thelength-1; i++){

            Animator animforthisround = TheAnimators[i];
            animforthisround.speed = 1;

        }

    }

}

public void Update(){


}

}
```

If you could help, that would be great, because I am stumped. I have looked everywhere and nothing is helping.

Comment: Try "animforthisround["animationName"].speed = 1". That might make a difference. Edit: Sorry didn't see it was an Animator. Maybe try calling the individual animations from the animator?

Comment: I know the "for" loop is working, but turning the animations back on again is not working. I know this because I put a "print" statement in the "for" loop.